# Make text larger than is already - javascript

Tags: javascript, fonts, size

Sorry if this a simple, but I can't get it right. The problem is that what I have makes the text smaller from a point. What I mean is that if there is some aleady large text, Then it will make that text small again. I need to make text larger than it was before. The styles for the elements containing the text are set through CSS, so just editing the style property wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance! - Tanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your text element have some id than it can be done easily. For example:

```
<p id="hey">This is my fabulous text that will change.</p>

<a onMouseover=document.getElementById('hey').style.fontSize='10'> Make it Tiny!</a>
<a onMouseover=document.getElementById('hey').style.fontSize='24'> Make it HUGE!!!</a>
```

Actually `document.getElementById('yourid').style.fontSize=yourvalue` this is the general code. Use it where you want to increase the text size again by direct writing the code or by calling a function.

Comment: Very glad to hear that it help you...:)